# How sharp will be a pulse sharpened with microwave transistors in a schmidt trigger configuration?

Tags: transistors, pulse, microwave

My hope is to make a 7-10V pulse generator, with pulse width in between the 100ps - 1ns. 
I think simply to use microwave transistors [2SC3356](http://www.cel.com/pdf/datasheets/ne85633.pdf) in a Schmidt trigger configuration to sharpen a pulse of 200ns rise time (say). 
For me, this seems more conventional, simple and cheap than using e.g. [SRD diode techniques](http://www.hp.woodshot.com/hprfhelp/5_downld/lit/diodelit/an918.pdf).
Unfortunately, I'm insufficiently skilled to understand from the datasheet of the transistor above how fast can I hope the rise time of the pulse be. 
Any insight ?

Comment: It’s got a hFE of 1 at 7 GHz. That’s an insight.

Comment: Probably for you Andy. You've forgotten that you are one of the best here. For me, I only think I understand from that the rise time could not be less than 200ps (say)

Comment: Actually, this might get rather more complicated than you think. Microwave transistors are intended to be used in linear mode, rather than the saturation implied by your usage. I'd expect them to be quick, but experimentation is definitely in order here.

Comment: Simulation will give you some idea of the performance.

Comment: The data sheet alone will not do. You need to know what load you're driving, and what amplifier configuration. You'll get better results in current mode than voltage mode, basically build ECL with discretes. Get the SPICE models and play in a simulator for a while, that will build your insight!

Comment: Probably. But I will not be able to link the results with the data in the datasheet. I'm reduced to a trial and error approach.

Comment: 7-10V seems a stretch at 100ps. You can however easily generate 6V transitions using an ATE pin driver such as one of these: https://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/specialty-amplifiers/pin-drivers.html

Comment: Why don't you think you can link the simulation to the datasheet? If you get the simulation model from the transistor manufacturer it should reliably model the typical behavior of the transistor. If the typical behavior isn't good enough then you have no hope.

Comment: for a meaningful simulation, the various 1nH ---- 5nH inductors should be included.

Comment: design your Schmidt to avoid Miller Effects. This means all the signal energy is being wisely used to control base-conductivity, not to charge the collector-base junction capacitance.

Comment: Elliot Alserson. That's not what I mean. I mean that if that transistor is not good for this task, I'll need to try simulating other transistors until I find the one that works. I have no clue to know a priori what transistor has good chances to work.

Comment: analogsystemsrf. How to do that? I know that the cascode configuration annihilates the Miller effect, but I'm not sure I know how to do a Schmidt trigger in cascode.